# ng-bootstrap - Icon for datepicker is not showing

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I imported the datepicker exactly as the documentation says

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
              name="date" [(ngModel)]="date" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" >
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm fairly certain I followed the guide as to setup correct.

Comment: Do you mean the calender icon in the button?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your image manually, I am using [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons) for this:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input name="date" class="form-control" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="date" required />
            <span class="input-group-append">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" (click)="d.toggle()">
                    <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt fa-fw"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah that would make sense. Though it was build into ng-bootstrap. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add the below CSS in your component stylesheet or in your `index.html` file just after the `bootstrap.css`

```
button.calendar, button.calendar:active {
  width: 2.75rem;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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') !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 23px;
  background-position: center;
}
```

check this official example in stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/run?file=index.html